# Настройка gulp.spritesmith

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Пытаюсь разобраться с плагином  `gulp.spritesmith`, исходя и оф. документации самая простая задача выглядит так:

```
gulp.task('imgsprite', function() {
    var spriteData = gulp.src('dev/**/sprite/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}')
    .pipe(spriteImg({
        imgName: 'sprite.png', // название собраного спрайта
        cssName: 'sprite.css', // название css файла
    }));
    var stylStream = spriteData.css
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'));

    var imgStream = spriteData.img
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'));

    return merge (imgStream, stylStream);
});
```

Что я хочу? Я хочу название спрайта генерировать автоматически, в зависимости от папки где лежат исходные картинки.
Допустим путь к картинам такой:
`dev/project/img/sprites/social/`
Значит собранный спрайт должен называться `social.png`
путь:
`dev/project/img/sprites/menu-icon/`
собранный спрайт должен называться `menu-icon.png`
Для чего это нужно?
В проекте может быть несколько спрайтов, соответственно исходные картинки размещаем в папке `sprites` и раскладываем по отдельным папкам, название которой и будет именем генерируемого спрайта.
Вторая задача - это пути выходных файлов, лежат исходные картинки допустим по пути `dev/project/img/sprites/menu-icon/`, значит генерированный спрайт должен положиться `app/project/img/menu-icon.png`.
Насколько я понимаю нужно анализировать путь к файлам, которые попали в `gulp.src`, вытаскивать нужные фрагменты, обрабатывать, сохранять в переменные и уже затем использовать их в настройках `gulp.spritesmith`.
Но как это сделать придумать не могу.   Может быть я сейчас велосипед пытаюсь придумать и уже все есть, буду признателен если кто поделится решением. В сети ничего подобного не встречал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И так, в поисках решения данной задачи я столкнулся с несколькими проблемами, и самая главная - это не очень хорошее понимание процессов `NODE.js`
Вторая проблема - заключалась в получении путей к тем файлам, которые попали в `gulp.src`, дело в том, что у него нет метода который их возвращает. Он просто создает потоки данных используя `vinyl fs` и передает их для дальнейшей работы с ними.....
Что ж, а что же мешает создать собственный экземпляр `glob` объекта, тем более последним аргументом конструктор принимает колбэк, в который первым приходит объект ошибки, если таковая случилась, а вторым массив с файлами попавшими в выборку. То что и нужно!.
Осталось подключить модуль `glob` , ну и заодно `merge-stream`, понадобиться для объединения источников спрайта и файла стилей к нему в один выходной поток.

```
var glob = require("glob").Glob;
var glob = require("glob").Glob;
```

Ну и создадим саму задачу, создадим в ней новый `glob` объект с интересующей выборкой и введем несколько переменных:

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
  var tmp = new glob('dev/**/sprite/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', {}, function(err, matches) {
    var dirnames = [];          // имена каталогов с картинками для спрайтов
    var files = [];             // массив с данными для spritesmith
    var destination = [];       // каталоги назначения

  });
});
```

Далее сформируем массивы с именами каталогов - его будем использовать для названий выходных файлов и массивом с путями назначения - там будут лежать пути, по которым необходимо разложить полученные спрайты.
Для этого пройдемся в цикле по массиву `matches` и вытащим необходимую инфу, а в него попадает
[image: вот что]
Красным выделено то, что попадет в `dirnames`, синим в `destination`.

```
for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        var itemPath = matches[i].split('/'); 
        dirnames.push(itemPath[itemPath.length - 2]);
        itemPath[0] = 'app';
        itemPath.length = 4;
        itemPath.push('/');
        destination.push(itemPath.join('/'));
    }
    dirnames = Array.from(new Set(dirnames));
    destination = Array.from(new Set(destination));
```

теперь наши массивы выглядят так:
[image: М]
Теперь необходимо заполнить массив `files`, для этого снова воспользуемся циклом, но теперь уже по массиву `dirnames`, ведь в нем лежат название каталогов с картинками для спрайтов и соответственно сколько каталогов, столько и необходимо объектов в массиве `files` ключи которого будут:
 `data` - это массив, в нем будут лежать пути к картинкам в определенном каталоге (этот же массив и будум передавать в `gulp.src`, он же принимает массив с путями... вот и чудно).
`filename` - сюда положим название каталога и будем использовать для названия спрайта и стилей к нему.

```
for(var i = 0; i < dirnames.length; i++) {
        files[i] = {};
        files[i].data = [];
        files[i].filename = dirnames[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < matches.length; j++) {
            if(matches[j].indexOf(dirnames[i]) != -1) {
                files[i].data.push(matches[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

И еще один цикл, что-бы добавить в каждый объект путь для спрайта:

```
for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        files[i].destImg ='';
        for(var j = 0; j < destination.length; j++ ) {
            var str = destination[j].split('/');
            if(files[i].data[0].indexOf(str[2]) != -1) {
                files[i].destImg = destination[j];
            }
        }
    }
```

В итоге получим:
[image: ф]
Ну и осталось теперь пройтись по массиву `files` и для каждого объекта в нем выполнить функцию:

```
files.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
         var spriteData = gulp.src(arr[i].data)
         .pipe(spriteImg({
            imgName: arr[i].filename + '.png',
            cssName: arr[i].filename + '.css',
            imgPath: '../img/' + arr[i].filename + '.png'
        }));
        var stylStream = spriteData.css
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/tmp/' + arr[i].filename + '/'));

        var imgStream = spriteData.img
        .pipe(gulp.dest(arr[i].destImg))

        return merge (imgStream, stylStream); 
    });
```

В итоге все спрайты разложаться по нужным директория, названия спрайта будет соответствовать названию каталога в котором лежали исходные картинки, а стили сложатся в паку `tmp` в корне проекта и так же будут разложены по папкам с названиями каталогов.
[image: ш]
Весь код полностью:

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
  var tmp = new glob('dev/**/sprite/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', {}, function(err, matches) {
    var dirnames = [];          // имена каталогов с картинками для спрайтов
    var files = [];             // массив с данными для spritesmith
    var destination = [];     // каталоги назначения
    for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        var itemPath = matches[i].split('/');
        dirnames.push(itemPath[itemPath.length - 2]);
        itemPath[0] = 'app';
        itemPath.length = 4;
        destination.push(itemPath.join('/'));
    }
    dirnames = Array.from(new Set(dirnames));
    destination = Array.from(new Set(destination));
    for(var i = 0; i < dirnames.length; i++) {
        files[i] = {};
        files[i].data = [];
        files[i].filename = dirnames[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < matches.length; j++) {
            if(matches[j].indexOf(dirnames[i]) != -1) {
                files[i].data.push(matches[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        files[i].destImg ='';
        for(var j = 0; j < destination.length; j++ ) {
            var str = destination[j].split('/');
            if(files[i].data[0].indexOf(str[2]) != -1) {
                files[i].destImg = destination[j];
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(files)
    files.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
         var spriteData = gulp.src(arr[i].data)
         .pipe(spriteImg({
            imgName: arr[i].filename + '.png',
            cssName: arr[i].filename + '.css',
            imgPath: '../img/' + arr[i].filename + '.png'
        }));
        var stylStream = spriteData.css
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/tmp/' + arr[i].filename + '/'));

        var imgStream = spriteData.img
        .pipe(gulp.dest(arr[i].destImg))

        return merge (imgStream, stylStream); 
    });
  });
});
```

P.S Возможно кто-то более опытный сделает лучше и красивее, буду рад если поделится....